# Saddle.Exchange Docker image will not open

Tags: contract-deployment, docker, hardhat, blockchain-fork, hardhat-deploy

Please forgive me. I'm wildly inexperienced. This my first attempt at forking a project. This is for educational purposes.

I've successfully deployed the saddle front end using vercel, and now I'm moving backwards.

I'm attempting to fork the Saddle contracts --https://github.com/saddle-finance/saddle-contract

I noticed they included a dockerfile, so I cloned the repo and attempted to build an image with it.

Initially it failed-- no .env file so some unassigned stuff in the hardhat config file broke everything.

I added one with the three necessary variables (as far as I could tell): alchemy API, both mainnet and ropsten, and a secret key for the test account (which I left an empty space in assuming it would be unnecessary on hardhat network)

Successfully created image.

But now when I try to run the container I get this error:

"Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container': Error:(HTTP code 400) unexpected - invalid reference format"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that there is a "saddle-contract" in the docker hub, but I would like to run a private one